# .net system independent font size

Tags: .net, windows, fonts, size

I have a custom windows forms .net window with several text boxes. Text boxes has always the same font size (courier new 10).
There's hard coded box resizing logik which only works when the font size stays the same.

For some reason, on one machine, the font size is different.
I think it depends on some custom system font settings. (windows 7 machine)

Is that possible? Can you "override" how a font is displayed?
If yes, is there any way to avoid that behavior? 
I just always want the texboxes to have the same font size.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, the font size is not going to stay the same.  It gets harder and harder to ignore this problem, "retina" resolution displays are getting common.  Your form will be between unusable and dead-ugly on such a display.  You'll need to stop ignoring this problem, there's no good reason for needing the resize logic to be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Is that possible? Can you "override" how a font is displayed?
```

I think it is not possible.
Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944813/1758762

In Windows, under Desktop settings you have option of increasing the screen font size without changing the resolution. If you increase screen font size then the Dot per pixel changes which can measure different pixel size for same text on different machine.

This is due to fact that old people can not read smaller fonts, thats why they can increase the font size in desktop settings ...

Comment: Hahah. DPI is DPI, it's not designed to help those with poor eyesight blow up fonts. It's so you can specify an inch in code and have it show up as an inch on the screen. Not super important in the past, but pretty relevant now for touchscreens.

Comment: @Cory, DPI is as a per-user setting in windows, not per screen. I agree with you that DPI should mean dots per inch but windows obviously has another definition.